# How to make a multiline string value from MongoDB's bson.M in Golang?

Tags: mongodb, go, telegram, telegram-bot, bson

I'm creating a telegram bot using Golang, and I need some advice on how to retrieve a multiline string value from function in Golang, that has same logic like this Python string

```
answer = """1 John 95
2 Sam 89
3 Mike 72"""
```

I have a function that creates a MongoDB request that gets me a data in bson.M datatype. And after that I need to send this queried data to a user as a single string value using this form:

```
msg := tgbotapi.NewMessage(
    update.Message.Chat_ID,
    answer,
)
bot.Send(msg)
```

I don't really know how to transform this bson.M data into a single multiline string.

bson.M response that I get from the function:

```
[map[_id:ObjectID("62a4acf2a494a2814238c6e1") bandMember:John name:School12 points:95] 
map[_id:ObjectID("62a4acf2a494a2814238c6e2") bandMember:Sam name:School15 points:89] 
map[_id:ObjectID("62a4acf2a494a2814238c6e3") bandMember:Mike name:School7 points:72]]
```

And I have to insert it in a string variable of "answer" (see above example)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, the problem is not about indexing. I need to collect all the data into a string variable, in order to insert it in a one single bot "answer" response with all this data (code form above). In this case, I don't want to make three different messages sending to user by looping each element and inserting in into a new message.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems do you have? Query the documents, use a loop and build the string either by concatenating or using a more efficient and sophisticated solution like `strings.Builder`. Post a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you guys for your time. The strings.Builder led me to the correct way to solve this problem. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the documents and sprintf a line for each document. Join the lines with newline to get the final result.

```
var lines []string
for i, m := range data {
    lines = append(lines, fmt.Sprintf("%d %s %d", i+1, m["bandMember"], m["points"]))
}
result := strings.Join(lines, "\n")
```